# Selenium Webdriver TestNG (Java) using While loop for all tests

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, java, testng, selenium3

I am new to Selenium Webdriver Testng and trying to Develop Data Driven framework using CSVReader

I have 5 tests in Testng and have to run those all on different environments. So basically I have to pick a different url and client, but other pages, elements remain same.

My Question is, Where do I put while loop so that it reads first line and execute all the tests and then read second line and so on.

I tried initialize CSV reader at class level, before suite, before method etc. but it throws error, it works for a particular test if I am putting inside `@Test` but that doesn't resolve the purpose, I couldn't find any relevant answer on the internet.

Below is the high level code:

```
public class Portal1 {
    WebDriver driver;
    @BeforeSuite
    public void beforeMethod() {
    }
    @BeforeTest
    public void SetUp() {
    config = new Configreader();

    }
@DataProvider(name = "TestData") 
public Object [][] getData() { Object [][] 
data=new Object[2][2]; 
data[0][0]="url1"; 
data[0][1]="client1"; 
data[1][0]="url2"; 
data[1][1]="client2"; 
return data; 
} 

@Test(dataProvider = "TestData",priority =0) 
public void RI_Select_an_Employer_page(String url,String client) throws Exception { 
driver.get(url); 
} 
@Test(dataProvider = "TestData",priority =1) 
    public void RI_Employer_Information_page(String url,String client) {
    WebElement  linkclient = driver.findElement(By.linkText(client));
    linkclient.click();
  @AfterMethod
          public void tearDown(ITestResult result) {
        }
  @AfterSuite
  public void tearDown() {
  driver.quit();
  }
```

Answer (score 3):

You shouldn't use while loops to provide test data to your tests if you use some dedicated test frameworks like TestNg.

Instead you should use the mechanisms provided by such frameworks. For TestNg you can provide test data either through xml file or though a special method providing test data for each run.

Details: http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#parameters

For example if you would like your tests are fed with test data from excel, then you should implement code like this (a bit changed code from the documentation example):

```
@DataProvider(name = "test1")
public Object[][] createData1() {

    int n = 0; // Load the number of the excel file rows later here
    int k = 0; // Load the number of parameter later here

    // Read your excel file. Assign the corresponding values to n and k

    Object[][] testData = new Object[n][k];

    // Fill testData with values from excel

    return testData;

}
```

Then you just describe your test methods in the following way:

```
@Test(dataProvider = "test1")
public void verifyData1(Object[] params) {
    // Here you use params[0], params[1], .. to take 
    // new set of parameters for each new run of your test.
    // testNg will automatically run your single test for
    // one time for EACH test data entry
}
```

I would also recommend to read carefully TestNg documentation to learn what are the other interesting things you can use to make your tests more effective.

**UPD:** I have tested the code from your question and it works fine for me:

[image]

Comment: I think reading from Excel or CSV is the easiest way to maintain test data, we can update the CSV, Excel files very easily, in case we need to update test data. I wanted to create a framework where a novice person can just go and update data in excel sheet and run the execution. Even if I put data in XML, looping would still be required to run the same tests multiple times for different test data. Let me know what you think ?

Comment: Looping is not required whatever way you want do choose. TestNg just gives you an abstraction allowing you to implement any data provider you need. If you think Excel would be more convenient for your users, then you just implement that method in the way to fetch records from excel file.

Comment: Thanks Alexey, I'll try to implement Dataprovider and see if my problem is handled as I am expecting it to be, I'll respond here after I have tried it.

Comment: Hi Alexey, I tried to implement @Dataprovider, Again facing the same issue. I have 5 tests and I want all the tests to execute in all the iterations instead of Test1 getting executed multiple times leaving all other tests. How to achieve that ? My first test case picks a particular url, client and all other tests are based on test1, but what I see is only Test1 is getting iterated again and again. Please help.

Comment: You should annotate all your tests pointing them to the data provider.

Comment: I pointed all tests to Dataprovider, but still its iterating only first test and it tries to move to second test only when all iterations in First test are completed

Comment: Paste the representative and relevant code part to your question so that I can check what you're doing wrong.

Comment: Not sure how to format it properly, Basically I am calling url in first Test and client name in second, now both of the url and client should iterate and the subsequent tests dependent on the first two tests should also execute in each iteration, I have tried to point to dataprovider, but didn't work for me, do you have any link/video where its shown, so that I can take a look as the way I have pasted, I don't think you'll be able to understand, thanks

Comment: I found another similar question in another thread, but there is no solution provided, Are you sure it works ? I see that it moves to the second test only when all iterations in the first test are completed

https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/32010/how-to-test-using-one-excel-dataprovider-in-testng-for-multiple-test-cases

Comment: For simplicity I have not parameterized from excel yet, once it works I can work with excel.

Comment: I you read my comment carefully I was asking you to put the code to your question, not the comment to my answer.

Comment: I didn't know what you mean, Now I have updated the code in question, I hope thats what you meant, let me know if thats fine or you want me to send you code via email ? thanks

Comment: check my update. (everything is working as expected. two methods * two line of parameters = 4 runs in total)

Comment: Hi Alexey, Thanks for trying but I can assure you that this is some kind of illusion, I have total 6 Tests and it does show me 12 runs (11 passed and 1 fail). When I see it executing, It opens browser in first test, opens url and closes it, Now it again opens browser, opens second url and then continues the whole execution twice, I don't know where the issue is, but this is not happening, I have screenshots at every step, and it is running subsequent Tests twice on the second url instead of running all for first url and then for second url. Your example is very generic so can't catch the thing

Comment: I have just taken your code and changed stuff with webdrvier to stuff with System.out. So this is your example ) I believe your issue is somewhere out of TestNg, but rather in the logic of your tests.

Comment: This logic is executing the same test twice at the same time instead of iterating all at once and then going the second iteration. So you think you are getting correct results, but if you put any dependency where the second iteration should show a little different output, you'll find the difference. I am not sure if this is how its designed or there is another way to what I am looking for (very basic thing as per test automation).

Comment: My first test decides the flow by picking a specific client, but it executes both at the same time and it goes ahead with second url (as first was closed in first iteration of first test) and executes every test twice for the second url. I hope you understand what I mean.

Comment: I'll modify my question as per my latest problem and post it again, I am still hunting for appropriate answer

Comment: https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/35008/how-to-control-testng-to-iterate-all-tests-in-each-iteration-instead-of-iteratin

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in a simple way. Read the data from CSV and store it in data provider and after that and while writing test pass it as parameter. Below is just an example .

```
 @Test(dataProvider = "TestData",priority =1) 
       public void RI_Employer_Information_page(String url,String client) {
       driver.get(url);
       WebElement  linkclient = driver.findElement(By.linkText(client));
       linkclient.click();
       }
```

it will run for all the different 'url' and client.